# Mongo connection leak with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a `Servlet` with `static Mongo = new Mongo()` and `Morphia morphia = new Morphia()` objects. Each time `GET` is invoked, I do the following:

```
doGet(...){
...
datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, dbName);
...
}
```

I don't close `datastore`, because there is no close method. Each time i invoke the servlet, number of used connections in mongo grow:

```
{ "current" : 113, "available" : 706, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(122) }
> db.serverStatus().connections { "current" : 115, "available" : 704, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(124) }
> db.serverStatus().connections { "current" : 116, "available" : 703, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(125) }
> db.serverStatus().connections { "current" : 121, "available" : 698, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(130) }
> db.serverStatus().connections { "current" : 122, "available" : 697, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(131) }
> db.serverStatus().connections { "current" : 128, "available" : 691, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(137) }
```

what is the right way to close connections with mongo and morphia and where the connection is really leaking? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `singleton`  `Datastore` object

```
public enum MongoDBHelper { // the best way to implement singletons, due to the author of Effective Java  
INSTANCE;

private DB db;
private Datastore datastore;

private final String SERVER_URL = "...";
private final int SERVER_PORT = ...;
private final String USERNAME= "...";
private final String PASSWORD = "...";
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "...";

private MongoDBHelper() {

    try {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(SERVER_URL, SERVER_PORT);

        this.db = mongoClient.getDB(DATABASE_NAME);
        this.db.authenticate(USERNAME,PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        Morphia morphia = new Morphia();

        this.datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, DATABASE_NAME);

        morphia.mapPackage("package");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public DB getDB() {
    return this.db;
}

public Datastore getDatastore() {
    return this.datastore;
}
}
```

and now you can reuse the same `Datastore` object in your application

```
 Datastore datastore = MongoDBHelper.INSTANCE.getDatastore()
```

Comment: I would also be curious what your query code looks like.  It's possible to leak with .fetch() if you're not careful even you manage your MongoClients correctly.

Comment: @evanchooly it looks like any query, the problem is to avoid opening useless connections and not to avoid fetch trips

Comment: But that's just it, you might be doing something suboptimal but without code it's hard to tell.

Comment: @evanchooly I hear you mate, but its difficult to discuss all aspects in a single answer

Comment: The only question is if single datastore instance is safe to use from two servlets running at the same time?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. I am creating singleton MongoClient and Class specific DAO object. How this approach will work in Architecture with DAO?